# Text overflows in a div

Tags: html, css, ajax

I am making a dynamic search where my dynamic results overflow from the main container, I have tried different height options but I am not able to figure out why my results inside display_reults section would overflow out of the content div. I am using ajax based search to get results.
Here is my css:

```
.tabs {
  position: relative;   
  min-height: 200px; /* This part sucks */
  clear: both;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
.tab {
  float: left;
}
.tab label {
  background: #eee; 
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  margin-left: -1px; 
  position: relative;
  left: 1px; 
}
.tab [type=radio] {
  display: none;   
}

.content  {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: #eee;
  right: 81px;
  bottom: 0;
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 

  height:auto;
block:inline;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  z-index: 1;
}
#search_query
{margin-left:10px;
margin-right: 10px;
width: 325px;
}
 #acadsearch {   float: left; min-height: 28px; width: 330px; position: relative; top: 1px; left: 5px; }
               #acadsearchform { display: inline; position: relative; }
                  .acadsearchbox { font-family: "proxima-nova",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-weight: normal;  }
                  .acadsearchbox { border: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; position: relative; top: -1px; left: 0px; width: 303px; height: 20px; color: #00467f; padding-left: 3px;  }
                  .acadsearchbox_submit { border: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; position: absolute; top: -3px; left: 287px; width: 19px; height: 22px; }
 #progbyschool { font-family: "proxima-nova",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-weight: normal;   }                 
#progbyschool {  border: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; position: relative; top: -1px; left: 0px; width: 452px; height: 78px; color: #00467f; padding-left: 3px; }
 #progbycampus { font-family: "proxima-nova",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-weight: normal; }                 
#progbycampus {  border: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; position: relative; top: -1px; left: 0px; width: 418px; height: 22px; color: #00467f; padding-left: 3px; }
#acad_nav_1_a { margin: -1px 0px 0px 0px; color: #00467F; }
            #acad_nav_1_a a { color: #00467F; text-decoration: underline; }          
            #acad_nav_1_a a:hover { color: #47aa42; }
            #acad_nav_1_a ul li { list-style: none outside none; display: inline; margin-left: 5px; }
ul.a
 {
 display:block;}            

#livesearch
  { 
  margin:0px;
  width:194px; 
  }
#txt1
  { 
  margin:0px;
  } 
<style type="text/css">
  #main {
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 100px;
   margin-left: 300px;
   color: Green;
   border: 1px dotted;
   width: 520px;
  }
  #display_results_1 {
  color: #00467F;
 position: relative;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 330px;
  margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:auto;
  }

    #display_results_2 .ul {
   position: relative;
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-top: 10px;
  color: #00467F;
  display:table-cell;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 330px;
  }

    #display_results_2 {
  color: #00467F;
   position: relative;
   margin-left: 1px;
   margin-top: 10px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 454px;

  }

  #display_results_3 {
  color: #00467F;
   position: relative;
   margin-left: 1px;
   margin-top: 10px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 419px;

  }

  #display_results_3_a li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#content_main .majors-list li {
    border-top: 2px solid #E5E5E5;
    list-style-type: none !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

And this is  my html:

```
<br />
<div class="grid_10">
<div class="tabs">
<div class="tab">
       <input checked="checked" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" value="tab-1" type="radio" />
       <label for="tab-1">Programs</label>
<div class="content">


    <input id="search_query" name="search_query" placeholder="Search available undergraduate programs" size="50" type="text" />
<div id="display_results_1">
<div style="clear: left; height: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider making a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to summarize the issue.

Comment: Please consider reducing the amount of code to look at and using jsfiddle or similar if that is not possible.

Comment: Fiddle won't be possible since this is a ajax based search, I can post an image if that may help?

Comment: An image would be great too, and please reduce the code to only what's relevant

Comment: Here is the link to the image: http://www.2imgs.com/e8c694be6d

Comment: I see `grid_10` as a class name, are you using a CSS framework? if so, which one?

Comment: Yes, we are using 960.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the code is a bit complex BUT I think the issue is around `.content`.

I took your code and made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/397PZ/

and tidied up the CSS a bit.

```
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    left: 0;
    background: #eee;
    right: 81px;
    min-height: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height:auto;
}
```

The problem was that you set the offset `bottom: 0` which constrained the height of the container block;

This will probably take care of it.

Comment: Thank you so much Marc, I did not realize that the offset property was doing it, cannot thank you enough. But now that I have content box stretching, it flows on top of my footer, but not pushes the footer down, what could be causing that?
Thanks again.

Comment: I suspect that the absolutely positioned block is extending further down than you expected.  Since absolutely positioned blocks are out of the flow of the document, the footer does not know that the absolute block exists, so the footer does not get out of the way.  You could achieve the same layout without absolute positioning, and that would probably solve the problem.  You might be trying to extend a background color outside of its parent container which is causing some issues.  If you don't mind a vertical scroll bar, try setting `overflow: auto` on `.content`.

Comment: Is there any alternate that can push the footer down as the content box expands, and I can keep posiiton absolute?

Comment: Some JavaScript/jQuery fix, but I would rethink why I am using absolute positioning in the first place.  How would it work if you tried `position: relative`?

Comment: This is something I need working by end of the day today with multiple fixes, so something that can be a quick fix rather than working back after changing positions, I am still debating.